# Python - I want to know using count method without brackets

Tags: python

```
word = input().upper()
word_list = list(set(word))

cnt = []
for i in word_list:
  count = word.count
  cnt.append(count(i))

if cnt.count(max(cnt)) > 1:
  print("?")

else:
  print(word_list[(cnt.index(max(cnt)))])
```

in this code, look at the line6, count=word.count, count function is used.
I know that count function must be used like '.count()' this formation.
But in this case, '' is not used.
So I want to know how it is possible and how it can run very well.

+) when I print(type(word.count)), <built-in method count of str object at 0x01DD8800> is returned!

Answer (score 0):

`word.count` is a bound method of `word`. Normally, you'd bind the method and then call it immediately with `word.count(i)`, but it's perfectly legal to bind the method (attaching the instance to it for when it's called in the future), then call it at some later point. That's all you did here, you made `count` equivalent to `word.count`, then called it later providing the argument it required, as if you'd called `word.count(i)` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like `count = word.count()` what you are doing is calling the word.count function and assign the value that the function returns to the count variable. When you do `count = word.count` what you are really doing is assing the function pointer to the count variable so now count points to the same thing as word.count and you can now use it call that with `count()` and now it is basically the same thing as `word.count()` and if you do `print(word.count)` and `print(count)` it will give you the same output in both saying you the pointer of the function